# Data-Bind List-View using Knockout inside a Collapsible Set

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I want to have a **list view** inside a **collapsible-set** and I want to bind the data to the list view using **knockout.js**. Please can anyone help me regarding this with a simple example. I want to bind data in place of **Content 1**, **Content 2** and **Content 3** of the below code.

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed="false" data-icon="" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-iconpos="right">
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Collapsible 1</h3>
                    <div data-role="listview">
                        <p>Content 1</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Collapsible 2</h3>
                    <div data-role="listview">
                        <p>Content 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Collapsible 3</h3>
                    <div data-role="listview">
                        <p>Content 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You probably want to use the [foreach](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) binding. Either that or, if you want to display items in each list using the same template you probably want to use the [template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) binding with the foreach property set to your collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some specifics regarding the javascript structure to which the knockout binds is not provided, thus I'll have to provide a very generic [example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/jUe3c/).

Assuming the `collapsible` elements are part of an array and the `listview` contents belonging to each are a property:

### Javascript

Object to represent a  `collapsible` element:

```
var Section = function(title, content){
  return {
          title: title,
          content: content, 
          listViewData: new List(title)
        }
}
```

where `List` is just a function to populate an array with "dummy" data.

```
var List = function(title){
  var temp = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    temp.push({text: title + ': ' + i})
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Setup the `collapsible` behavior, ensuring the call is after `applyBindings`:

```
 ko.applyBindings(modelInstance)
 $("div[id^='collapsible']").collapsible()
```

### HTML

```
<div class="ui-body-d tablist-content" data-role="collapsible-set" data-bind='foreach: items'>
 <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'collapsible-'+ $index}">
    <h3 data-bind='text: title'></h3>

    <p> <span data-bind='text: content'></span>

     <ul data-role="listview" data-bind="foreach: { data: listViewContents, as: 'listItem'}">
       <li><a href="#" data-bind="text: listItem.text"></a></li>
     </ul>

    </p>
</div>
```